# Strange characters in text/html encode in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I have a text/html inin a ".txt" file. I get him by jquery.ajax().
In other browsers, I get the content without problems, but in firefox i got strange caracters how �...

my code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "menuProcesso.txt",
            cache: false,
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "text",
            async: false
        }).done(function (msg) {

            $("#resultado").html(msg);

        });
```

return in IE and Chrome:

```
"<ol class='sortable ui-sortable'><li id='1.7.5.3'  class='mjs-nestedSortable-branch mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed' proc='TSTDIOGO'><span class='disclose ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick' title='Mostrar/Ocultar filhos'>...."
```

return in firefox:

```
"��<ol class='sortable ui-sortable'><li id='1.7.5.3'  class='mjs-nestedSortable-branch mjs-nestedSortable-collapsed' proc='TSTDIOGO'><span class='disclose ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick' title='Mostrar/Ocultar filhos'><span></span></span><div class='liPai' onclick='mostraSite("", this,"TSTDIOGO")'>Processo de Teste de inclus�o</div><ol><li id='1.7.5.3.1'  class='mjs-nestedSortable-branch mjs-nestedS......"
```

Comment: What happends when you clear the text file and add just a word? does it still happen?

Comment: this archive is constantly changed... No problems if not contains accents or special characters...

Comment: encode your text file in UTF8. But then why issue only on FF, maybe cache issue or i don't know. Maybe set UTF8 encoding in HTML page too

Comment: this ".txt" file content is created by vbscript page and use de charset UCS-2 Little Endian

Comment: but are you sure its a problem with firefox maybe chrome and ie removes it automaticly...

Comment: If I convert, works... but when the file is changed, back to UCS-2... Maybe i have change the encode on vbscript page...

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set charset in `<head>` for html page.
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
I change the vbscript that write the ".txt" file to write in utf-8 encode, using a Stream...
Thank's all!!